# Microservice Pattern To Retrieve Data From Old Database And Write To New Database

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, microservices

I am given a situation where there is a database and it's getting used from last 6 months. But from now on, a new database will be used. All the insertion operation would happen in the new database but for retrievals or all gets, a search has to be made in both the old and new databases. Design a microservice and how can the database configuration be done to achieve this?

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. Why do you still need to use the old database? Which database technology do you use? Why are you introducing new database? Do you mean having 2 databases by design for some business case? Or do you only have 2 for some temporary period of time?

Answer (score 0):

Though not practical but you can define multiple DataSource in your spring boot project. Define a controller that intercept the get call. route the call to your service which will have the logic to transact between two different sources to build response for your rest queries. You can find an example from here :-

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Another thing you can do is introduce, elastic search and index all your old db data which will be part of get inquiry call to it and use elastic to fire query than db.